# I need to reformat text within a document

Tags: python, ruby

Currently the text is formatted like this :

"Number Name [identifier]"

There are spaces as indicated between each and the brackets exist around the identifier, the quote marks are just for example.

I am trying to reformat it to look like

"Name, identifier, variable, number"

In this example the commas do need to be in place (no quote marks) and the variable is something I would just need to set to either a "1 or 2" throughout the entire document.

The name and number will be directly pulled from (lets say) text file A and reformatted and saved into file B.  The identifier actually has some additional formatting that would need to take place.

The identifier comes in a 3 letter format (IE 'AKA').  Which correlates to something specific which I can define within some code (IE 'AKA' = 'Alsoknownas').

So in total I believe I am trying to

1.reformat the name and quantity directly from document a and saved in a new document (b)
2.manually define a variable before the script / code executes on 'a' then saves to new document 'b'.
3.Recognize the 3 digit identifier code in each line of document A, change it to something new in document b.  So i'll need some sort of data base to have the script pull from (ie, read AKA on the line in document 'a' and look it up in a database or something then exchange AKA for Alsoknownas and input that into document b before saving).

IF this all makes sense I would love anyones input on what your approach would be for this.  The identifiers are always going to be 3 alpha numeric characters, and they will always correlate to a alpha numeric string.  so AKA always = Alsoknownas, FYI always = Foryourinformation etc... etc..

Thanks for any input!

Comment: yea makes sense, what code have you written?

Comment: I am very new to writing code. I have dabbled with java and ruby. This is part of a project my friend and I are working on. He has much more experience. As far as I know he has coded in python, ruby, and some java script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you achieve what you want with a function that takes in the original string and the variable and then outputs the "reformatted" string?

You can you use the `string.split()` function in python to turn a string into a list of the pieces of the string. By default, it looks for space characters and breaks up the string from those. E.g.:

```
'a b c'.split()
```

becomes

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I suspect the split() function would be the key to the solution you're searching for.

Here's some code that may achieve what you want. Maybe you could use a dictionary object to turn identifiers into their long descriptions? How practical this is depends on how many identifiers you have, how often they might change, etc.

```
#dictionary of identifiers and their long descriptions
idLkUp = {'AKA': 'Alsoknownas',
          'FYI': 'Foryourinformation',
          }

inputStr = '5 Robert [FYI]'
variable = '1'

def reformatInputStr(inputStr, variable):
    # Expected input pattern: 'Number Name [Identifier]'
    #Returned output pattern: 'Name, Identifier, Variable, Number'
    splitStr = inputStr.split()
    splitStr[2] = splitStr[2].replace(']','').replace('[','')     #removes brackets from the Identifier
    strElements = {'Name': splitStr[1],
                   'Identifier': idLkUp[splitStr[2]],             #uses the idLkUp dictionary to get the long description of identifier
                   'Variable': variable,
                   'Number': splitStr[0],
                   }

    return '{Name}, {Identifier}, {Variable}, {Number}'.format(**strElements)

outputStr = reformatInputStr(inputStr, variable)
print(outputStr)
```

output:

```
Robert, Foryourinformation, 1, 5
```

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the time given. We will be working on this this evening.